# pronunciation help. What does the simple /i/ means

Tags: phonology, phonetics

The cambridge dictionary phonetics use phonetic symbol /i/ in addition to /I/ and /i:/

I assume they use the DJ phonetic transcription. The other source I read says that /i/ is the old spelling for /I/, but that apparently can not be the case because Cambridge dictionary lists /i/ separately alongside /i:/ and /I/ in their [help page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/help/phonetics.html#other). Can someone explain to me what does it entails, is it just a shorter version of /i:/?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The page you linked to has example words for those three symbols, with three different sounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between word-final iː, i and ɪ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207036/difference-between-word-final-i%cb%90-i-and-%c9%aa)